# Failed to start scene builder

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, java-8, scenebuilder

Whenever I try to open an fxml file with scenebuilder from Intellij it gives me this:

```
Failed to start SceneBuilder: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0"
```

[image: 1]

(I've already put in the path to scene builder from settings)

Comment: Is the Scene Builder standalone working? (Without trying to open it inside IntelliJ)

Comment: On a side note, the Oracle version of SceneBuilder is wildly out of date and has been replaced by [Gluon's Scene Builder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/). I'm not sure that's causing the issue, but it's possible.

Comment: Are there errors in [log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085)?

Comment: scene builder works standalone, and the gluon version gives me the same error

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that in Intellij IDEA settings you point to the executable file called *SceneBuilder* (in Gluon it is located under the *opt* folder)

Comment: When I do this, it won't open the Scene Builder unless I manually click "Open in SceneBuilder" in the context menu. However, that just opens the Scene Builder app in a separate window, not in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 5):

Please do the following steps:

1. Download and install `SceneBuilder` from [the website](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download) (Get the version respected to your Java, so if you use Java 8, then download the Scene Builder for Java 8)
2. Open IntelliJ -> File menu -> Setting -> Type "Scenebuilder"
3. Assign the location of SceneBuilder in your local machine to the path (Please find the attached image)

Now you should be able to open the `sample.fxml` file using `scenebuilder`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Saved Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0.exe

Solution: Go to the location where the scene builder 2.0 actual file exists and right click->properties->compatibility->**uncheck** run as administrator. Done

Answer (score 0):

1.Download and install the latest version of Scene Builder.

2.In the **Settings/Preferences** dialog ***Ctrl+Alt+S***, select **Languages and Frameworks | JavaFX**.

[Look at this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Li6U.png)

3.Click the Browse button in the **Path to SceneBuilder** field.

4.In the dialog that opens, select the Scene Builder application (executable file) on your computer and click OK.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvCVn.png)

5.Apply the changes and close the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to sceneBuilder file location right click and select properties and extract path:

[image]

2. Open IntelliJ -> File menu -> Setting -> Type "Scenebuilder"
3. Paste the path extracted from properties:

[image]